# XPath expression

Tags: xml, xpath

I have an XML file like this:

```
<lib:library>    
    <lib:book> XML </lib:book>
    <lib:book> XPath </lib:book>
    <lib:book> XSLT </lib:book>
    <lib:book> Java </lib:book>
    <lib:book> C++ </lib:book>    
</lib:library>
```

and I want to go the book[2]...I can of course doing something like //lib:Book[2]...and it works. It could happen that in the same XML file I have, for example , same tag name but different namespace; in this case my XPath expression does not work...

I can replace it doing:

//*[local-name() = "book"]

This expression returns all the book containined in the XML file...but what if I want to get the number [2]...how should I rewrite the XPath expression adding condition about number? Of course I do not want to consider namespaces, it must be valid for every used namespace.

Thanks
Luca

Comment: Good question, +1. This is a FAQ. And do you know that at present you have selected the wrong answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about `//*[local-name() = "book"][2]`? it should work.

As noted in the comments you should avoid using `//` unless you're really sure of what you're doing.

Comment: Yes it works...and what about this expression? //*[local-name() = 'book'][1]/[local-name() = 'author'][1] Let's suppose book can have multiple author as children

Comment: @luca: I would say that expression returns the first author of the first book.

Comment: This answer is wrong. In fact `//expression[2]` can select *many* nodes. Caution should be used with the XPath `//` pseudo-operator.

Answer (score 4):

**The currently-selected answer is wrong**.

In fact `//someExpression[2]` can select many nodes.

**For example, if we have the following XML document**:

```
<lib:library xmlns:lib="UNDEFINED!!!">
  <topic name="XML">
      <lib:book> XML </lib:book>
  </topic>
  <topic name="XPath">
      <lib:book> XPath </lib:book>
  </topic>
  <topic name="XSLT">
     <lib:book> XSLT1 </lib:book>
     <lib:book> XSLT2 </lib:book>
  </topic>
  <topic name="Imperative PLs">
     <lib:book> Java </lib:book>
     <lib:book> C++ </lib:book>
  </topic>
</lib:library>
```

**When the expression**:

```
   //*[local-name() = "book"][2]
```

is evaluated against the document above, **two nodes are selected** (and none of them is the second node in the document with the wanted properties):

```
<lib:book xmlns:lib="UNDEFINED!!!"> XSLT2 </lib:book>
<lib:book xmlns:lib="UNDEFINED!!!"> C++ </lib:book>
```

**Solution**: One way to select the `N`th (say 2nd) node (say `lib:book`) in the whole document is:

```
   (//*[local-name() = "book"])[2]
```

When this expression is evaluated on the document above, the correct, single node is selected:

```
<lib:book xmlns:lib="UNDEFINED!!!"> XPath </lib:book>
```

**Explanation**: As defined in the **[W3C XPath recommendations](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#path-abbrev)**:

> `//` is short for `/descendant-or-self::node()/`

Therefore:

```
//someName[2]
```

is a shorthand for:

```
/descendant-or-self::node()/someName[2]
```

and this selects any element in the document named `someName` and which is the second `someName` child of its parent.

To put it in other words, the `[]` operator binds more strongly (has higher precedence) than the `//` pseudo-operator. This is why we need brackets to override the default operator precedence.